# Error in Custome Spring-Jpa

Tags: java, jpa

The below query is working fine in mysql.

```
SELECT * FROM utilization u INNER JOIN sbg s on s.sbg_code=u.sbg_code where u.sbg_code=104
```

I have written below JPQL query.

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Utilization i,i.sbg s where s.sbgCode = :sbgCode")
        public ArrayList<Utilization> findUtilization(@Param("sbgCode") int sbgCode);
```

I am getting below error, please tell how to resolve this error

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: i.sbg is not mapped [SELECT i FROM be.g00glen00b.model.Utilization i,i.sbg s where s.sbgCode = :sbgCode]

Can you please tell me how to write the above sql query to JPQL query?
Please suggest some link to learn JPQL joins because I am new to this.

Below class represents the mapping between two tables

1. sbg class

   ```
   @Entity
   public class sbg {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private int sbgCode;

       private String sbgdesc;

       @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
       @JoinColumn(name="iccode")
       @JsonIgnore
       private Ic ic;

       @OneToMany(mappedBy="sbg1", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
       private List<Utilization> utilization;

       public int getSbgCode() {
           return sbgCode;
       }
       public void setSbgCode(int sbgCode) {
           this.sbgCode = sbgCode;
       }
       public String getSbgdesc() {
           return sbgdesc;
       }
       public void setSbgdesc(String sbgdesc) {
           this.sbgdesc = sbgdesc;
       }
       public Ic getIc() {
           return ic;
       }
       public void setIc(Ic ic) {
           this.ic = ic;
       }
   }
   ```
2. utilization class

   ```
   package be.g00glen00b.model;

   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.FetchType;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
   import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
   @Entity
   public class Utilization {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private int asset_type_key;
       private String asset_type;
       private String Engine_status;

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @JoinColumn(name = "sbgCode")
       private sbg sbg1;

       public sbg getSbg1() {
           return sbg1;
       }

       public void setSbg1(sbg sbg1) {
           this.sbg1 = sbg1;
       }

       public int getAsset_type_key() {
           return asset_type_key;
       }

       public void setAsset_type_key(int asset_type_key) {
           this.asset_type_key = asset_type_key;
       }

       public String getAsset_type() {
           return asset_type;
       }

       public void setAsset_type(String asset_type) {
           this.asset_type = asset_type;
       }

       public String getEngine_status() {
           return Engine_status;
       }

       public void setEngine_status(String engine_status) {
           Engine_status = engine_status;
       }
   }
   ```
3. jpa repository

   ```
   public interface UtilizationRepository extends JpaRepository<Utilization, Integer> {

       @Query("SELECT i FROM Utilization i,i.sbg s where s.sbgCode = :sbgCode")

       public ArrayList<Utilization> findUtilization(@Param("sbgCode") int sbgCode);
   }
   ```

Comment: Please check answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `JOIN` in your query.

Your query should look like

```
SELECT i FROM Utilization i JOIN i.sbg s where s.sbgCode = :sbgCode
```

When you do queries like this you need to keep in mind that you might get duplicate results back. If you want to get unique results you should use a `Set` or have a look at [this](http://in.relation.to/2016/08/04/introducing-distinct-pass-through-query-hint/) for a way to achieve it with hints and hibernate.